# Columns to dummies in R, example provided

Tags: r

I have a dataframe which looks like this

```
uid     language_name
1   333        English
2   333        French
3   333        Dutch   
4   654        Spanish 
5   546        English
6   546        French 
7   432        Afrikaans  
8   302        German
9   302        Dutch
```

And I want it looking like this:

```
uid     English              French               Dutch         ..........
1   333        1                   1                    1
2   654        0                   0                    0
3   546        1                   1                    0
4   432        0                   0                    0
5   302        0                   0                    1
```

So I want to change my language_name column into different dummy columns with the languages as their names. Is there a quick and easy way to do this?

Comment: Anything you already tried?

Comment: use `dcast` from `reshape2`

Comment: I tried working with the 'dummies' package. But I wasn't able to keep the 'uid' variable in. Also 'model.matrix', same problem. (I'm not that good at R)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `reshape2`. Like here:

```
library("reshape2")

dcast(cbind(z, ile=1), 
      uid~language_name, value.var="ile", fill=0) -> t

colnames(t)[-1] <- paste("Language_", colnames(t)[-1], sep="")
```

Comment: This works! Thanks a lot. Do you know how I could get 'Language' in front of every column name?

Comment: I've edited my answer to show you, how to change column names.

Answer (score 0):

Usually better way for such dummy coding is to use sparse matrices and `Matrix::sparse.model.matrix` :

```
Matrix::sparse.model.matrix(uid ~ -1 + ., data=your_data_frame)
```